# Google Line Chart make lines with same values both visable

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using a Google Line Chart to visualize data for a sports toto and it often happens that users have the same score for a few games/stages. Only one line is visible in that case:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ncgw.png (i'm not allowed to post images)

Is there a way to make both lines visible, so that we see the score of 2: Waalkens3 as well?

Comment: You can adjust point sizes and line widths on a series-by-series basis (use the `series.<series index>.pointSize` and `series.<series index>.lineWidth` options), which may help, but there is no way to make overlapping lines appear together.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the series option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved this by manipulating my json data by adding a couple of numbers if there are equal values. Like asgallant said, I don't think there is a way to make overlapping lines appear together with the google charts config options.